# Splitting a file line by line into array of words

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that converts C switch sentences to assembly.
My first step is to read from a file and to do a line by line splitting of lines into array of words.
And then process the words through its locations.

for example:
Hello World;
hello world;

would be turn into:
iteration 1: arr[0]= Hello, arr[1]= World
iteration 2: arr[0]= hello, arr[1]= world

for some reason I get nulls when I try print my arr contents and I don't know how to solve it.
Would appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fptrr;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    fptrr = fopen("switch.c", "r");
    if (fptrr == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    size_t num = 100;
    char **arr = malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptrr)) != -1){
        char* token = strtok(line, " ;");
        int i = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            arr[i] = malloc(100);
            strcpy(arr[i], token);
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ;");
            printf("%s ",arr[i]);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the file I'm trying to read:

```
long switch1(long *p1, long *p2, long action)
{
    long result = 0;
    switch(action) {
        case 27:
            *p2 = *p1;
            result = *p2;
            break;
        case 25:
            *p1 += *p2;
            result = *p1;
            break;
        case 29:
        case 30:
            *p1 -= 59;
            *p2 -= *p1;
            break;
        case 23:
            *p1 += 60;
        case 21:
            result = *p2;
            result *= result;
            break;
        case 31:
            result = *p2;
            result >>= *p1;
            break;
        default:
            result = 12;
            result <<= 3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is what I'm getting now:

```
(null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) switch1(long switch1(long *p1, long *p2, long result = {
 = 27:
 = 0 
 = *p1 

 = *p2 
 *p2 25:
 *p2 

 += *p2 

 = *p1 
 *p1 29:
 *p1 30:
 *p1 

 -= 59 

 -= *p1 
 *p1 23:
 *p1 

 += 60 21:
 60 

 = *p2 

 *= result 
 result 31:
 result 

 = *p2 

 >>= *p1 

 *p1 

 = 12 

 <<= <<= 3 
 result
```

Answer (score 1):

in the following line you only allocated memory for the pointers:

```
    char **arr = malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
```

You must allocate memory for each token, and then copy the entire token:

instead of :

```
arr[i] = token;
```

use:

```
arr[i] = malloc(100); strcpy(arr[i], token);
```

Note: above code snippet's purpose is to demonstrate the issue, not to show good programming practices. e.g. you must handle memory de-allocation, check overrun etc.

Comment: `getline` does the allocation, and `strtok` is returning pointers into the allocated memory.

Comment: Still getting weird stuff after using @nivpeled's remark.
Iv'e updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

These reason you only see NULL is because you increment `i` before the `printf("%s", arr[i])`. You may sometimes see a value different of null because `arr` contains tokens of previous lines.

Here is a corrected code:

```c
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptrr)) != -1){
        char* token = strtok(line, " ;");
        int i = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            arr[i] = token;
            printf("%s ",arr[i]);
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ;");
        }
    }
```

Comment: whilst that fixes the immediate problem, `arr` is going to be full of pointers to inside `line` so will contain random data once the file has been read - they should make fresh copies of the string `token` rather than assigning

Comment: @ChrisTurner I answered the question. I’m not solving the problem the OP tries to solve. There are obviously many problems ahead on the track he follows.